# Best setup of managed object contexts

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have read several tutorials that recommend using two (or more) `NSManageObjectContexts` when implementing core data, so as not to block the UI of the main queue. I am a little confused, however, because some recommend making the child context of the `persistent store coordinator` that of type `mainQueueConcurrencyType`, and then giving it its own child context of type `privateQueueConcurrencyType`, while others suggest the opposite.

I would personally think the the best setup for using two contexts would be to have the `persistent store coordinator` -> `privateQueueConcurrencyType` -> `mainQueueConcurrencyType`, and then only saving to the private context, and only reading from the main context. My understanding of the benefits of this setup is that saving to the private context won't have to go through the main context, as well as reading on the main context will always include the changes that are made on the private context.

I know that many apps require a unique solution that this setup might not work for, but as a general good practice, does this make sense?

**Edit:**

Some people have pointed out that this setup isn’t necessary with the introduction of `NSPersistentContainer`. The reason I am asking about it is because I’ve inherited a huge project at work that uses a pre-iOS-10 setup, and its experiencing issues.   I am open to re-writing our core data stack using `NSPersistentContainer`, but I wouldn't be comfortable spending the time on it unless I could find an example of how it should be setup with respect to our use cases ahead of time.

Here are the steps that most of our main use cases follow:

1) User edits object (eg. adds a photo/text to an abstract object).

2) An object (sync task) is created to encapsulate an API call to update the edited object on the server. Sync tasks are saved to core data in a queue to fire one after the other, and only when internet is available (thus allowing offline editing).

3) The edited object is also immediately saved to core data and then returned to the user so that the UI reflects its updates.

With `NSPersistentContainer`, would having all the writing done in `performBackgroundTask`, and all the viewing done on `viewContext` suffice for our needs for the above use cases?

Comment: with iOS 10, I feel there is no need of these setup, because from persistentContainer you can get main context or background context anytime you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @vivekDas. I edited my question to address your suggestion.

Comment: Have you watched any of the Core Data best practices videos from Apple? They are _full_ of advice about just this sort of thing.

Comment: @matt I've watched some and didn't feel like they addressed my setup. Can you suggest any?

Comment: Gosh, I thought the one from this year was pretty near the mark. But maybe not.

Comment: @matt thanks for the suggestion.... I'll check that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS10 you don't need to worry about any of this, just use the contexts `NSPersistentContainer` provides for you.

Comment: Thanks @trapper. Please see my updated question where I address your suggestion.

Comment: To address your edit; Any changes the user makes via the UI should be made and saved in the `viewContext`. For anything going on in the background create use and discard a `newBackgroundContext` - don't keep these hanging around longer than necessary or try to reuse the same one later, just get a new one for each background action.